# is there a way to Continuously check for a Pop Up? and Close the PopUp

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

is there a way to Continuously check for a Pop Up which can appear within any amount of time between 0 and 60

For example the below popup may appear at 20seconds or 30 seconds etc etc within the user journey and therefore will need to close it if present. 
[image]

Comment: Your question is too broad. You can use "polling" or "multi-threading" to accomplish this. Each comes with challenges and benefits. Google is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

When we get a web-pop-up site in page then use this code to accept pop-up 
first create a object
`example:`

```
 WebDriver driver=ChromeDriver();
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

to dismiss popup site

```
 driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

By using this code we can accept or dismiss web popup in page by using selenium webdriver.

Comment: thank you, is there a way to run a continuous check? because i dont know at what point of the user journey the pop may display

Thanks Again